# multiple definition and making sure function is correctly written

Tags: c

This is my .h file

```
#ifndef _test_h_
#define _test_h_

void new_cmd(void);
void open_cmd(void);
void close_cmd(void);
void close_all_cmd(void);
void save_cmd(void);
void save_as_cmd(void);
void save_all_cmd(void);
void print_cmd(void);
void exit_cmd(void);
void call(char *cmd_name);
struct {
char *cmd_name; 
void (*cmd_pointer)(void);
} file_cmd[] =
{ 
{"new", new_cmd},
{"open", open_cmd},
{"close", close_cmd},
{"save", save_cmd},
{"save as", save_as_cmd},
{"save all", save_all_cmd},
{"print", print_cmd},
{"exit", exit_cmd}};

#endif
```

This is my function file

```
void call(char *cmd_name){
int i;

scanf("Enter command: %c\n",cmd_name);

for(i = 0; i < sizeof(file_cmd); i++){
    if(strcmp(cmd_name, file_cmd[i].cmd_name) == 0){
        file_cmd[i].cmd_pointer();
        }
}
```

I just deleted all file_cmd functions because it seems for other people

and this is my main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(void){

char cmd;

call(cmd);

return 0;
}
```

More I want to know is that my function void call is correctly written.

when I try to compile, it says

1. expected 'char*' but argument is of type 'char'
2. multiple definition of 'file_cmd'
3. first define here.

I am so confused how to fix it.

Please help

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two *very* different errors that you really should have asked about in two different question, but I'll be nice and answer both anyway.

1. In the `main` function you have a variable named `cmd`. It is of type `char`. You pass it to the `call` function, which expects an argument of type `char *` (i.e. a null-terminated string).

   To fix this you first need to make sure that `cmd` is the correct type (i.e. `char *` instead of plain `char`). Secondly you need to make sure this pointer is actually pointing to a valid null-terminated byte string.

   In other words, something like this:

   ```
   char *cmd = "open";
   call(cmd);
   ```
2. C really only cares about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). A translation unit is a single source files with all included header files.

   The problem here is that variables can only be **defined** in a single translation unit. And since you define the variable `file_cmd` in a header file that is included in multiple source files, it will be defined in both translation units created from those two source files.

   The solution here is to only **declare** the variable in the header file, and *define* it in a single source file.

   For example, do something like this in the header file

   ```
   struct command_struct
   {
       char *cmd_name;
       void (*cmd_pointer)(void);
   };

   extern struct command_struct file_cmd[];
   ```

   Then in one source file (like your "function file")

   ```
   struct command_struct file_cmd[] = {
       // Your initialization...
   };
   ```

---

There are also other problems with your code, some of them will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For example the `sizeof` operator returns the size *in bytes*, not the number of elements in an array. To get the number of elements in an array you need to divide the byte-size of the full array with the byte-size of a single element. For example `sizeof file_cmd / file_cmd[0]`.

Do note that the division only works for *real* arrays, not pointers, and that arrays very easily decays to pointers (to their first element).